# Breadcrumb that shows multiple custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, breadcrumb

I've created two custom post types with some custom hierarchical taxonomies. In the navigation a link to the custom post type is displayed. When clicking on it, the user is forwarded to a page that displays the highest level hierarchical terms. He is now free to choose one and is then forwarded to a second page that shows the child terms of the taxonomy he clicked on. He can now choose one of these terms and is then forwarded to an archive page that displays all the articles of these categories.

For a better user experience I think it is essential, to tett the user where he is on the site. And therefore I want to implement a breadcrumb.
My breadcrumb works so far, but I have no idea how to show the correct path within posts.

Lets say there is a post named `Post 1` inside the custom post type `My Posts` that is categorized with the terms `Parent` and `Child`.

How can I code the breadcrumb out so that it says:

> Home / My Posts / Parent / Child / Post1

This should all work automatically. If a post has the term `Child2` insted of `Child` the breadcrumb should adapt. And if there are no child terms but only a parent term, it souldn't display a blank child term.

I hope you understand what I want to get.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Breadcrumbs can be _a lot_ of logic, which you can grasp if you look at any existing plugin. What is your _question_ here? For someone to write breadcrumbs from scratch? That scope is too wide. I would recommend to break this up into smaller and more specific issues. You don't know how to retrieve post parents? Start with asking about that, and so on.

Comment: @Rarst To be able to split the question up, I need an idea on how to achieve my goal. After having an idea on how to solve the problem, I can tell you which parts I can't code myself. But at this point I'm only standing in front of the problem without having an idea on how to solve it, so I can't split the questions up. Would you mind giving me a short explanation how you would code this out?

Comment: (1) enumerate every part I want in breadcrumb in each case, (2) figure out how to retrieve those parts starting with data I have, (3) figure out how to put them in meaningful order. (4) output result.

Comment: @Rarst Okay, thank you. Well how would you extract the parent term and – if available – the child term?

Comment: That would be a good separate focused question, not a comment discussion. :)